# Binding datacontext of usercontrol to mainwindow

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a UserControl positioned inside of the MainWindow.  The UserControl runs a query and populates certain TextBlocks within it.  I also want to populate TextBlock in the MainWindow from the same returned data.

How do I bind the MainWindow data to the UserControl?  I have tried this:

```
<MainWindow DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=UserControlName}">
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example.

The UserControl XAML contains just a two-way bound text box.  The relative source stuff is more verbose than you need, you could have a data context set above that, but it's just to make it clear where the property is coming from:

```
<TextBox x:Name="ucTextBox" 
         Text="{Binding Path=UcText, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:UserControl1}}, 
                        Mode=TwoWay, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

User Control code behind declares either a dependency property or, as shown here, a regular property implementing INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
private string _ucText;
public string UcText
{
    get { return _ucText; }
    set
    {
        _ucText = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("UcText");
    }
}
```

The MainWindow XAML then sets it's own text block to the text property from the textbox in the user control, like so:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UcText, ElementName=uc1}"/>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1" />
</StackPanel>
```

Nothing extra is required in the MainWindow codebehind.

What this results in is a text box (in the user control) which - as you type inside it - updates the text block on the main window.